# Prove that $a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)q^{l-1}(q-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^kq^l}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, alternative-proof

with $a$ an integer such that $\gcd(a,p^k q^l)=1$ ($p,q$ two distinct prime numbers and $k,l$ integers $\ge 1$).

Is there any elementary method to solve this without using the Euler's totient function and its multiplicative properties ?

> Do we have $\gcd(p,q)=1 \Rightarrow \gcd(p^k,q^l)=1$ ? All the powers
>   of $p$ and $q$ are divided respectively by $p$ and $q$ which are
>   different, is that enough ?
>
> But here's a more formal proof with a weaker hypothesis ($p,q$ not
>   necessarily prime numbers). Supposing $\gcd(p,q)=1$, so there exists $u,v\in
> \mathbb{Z}$ such that $up+vq=1$. Multiplying by itself it gives :
>   $1=u^2p^2+2uvpq+v^2q^2=(u^2p+2uvq)p+v^2q^2=1\Rightarrow
>  \gcd(p,q^2)=1$. Again, traducing the new hypothesis by Bachet-Bézout
>   theorem and multiplying by $(up+vq=1)$ it gives that
>   $\gcd(p,q^3)=1$. We repeat this $l-2$ times and it gives
>   $\gcd(p,q^l)=1$.
>
> It implies that there exists $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $up+vq^l=1$.
>   Multiplying by itself it gives $\gcd(p^2,q^l)=1$. This time we repeat
>   the operation $k-1$ times and it gives $\gcd(p^k,q^l)=1$.

So now, here's an elementary proof :

First thing is to prove with an induction on $k\ge 1$ that $a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^k} $.

*Initialisation* : for $k=1$ we found Fermat little theorem so it's true.

*Heredity* : for $k=k+1$ we want to prove that : $a^{p^{k}(p-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^{k+1}} $.

$a^{p^{k}(p-1)}= a^{p^{k-1}p(p-1)}=(a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)})^p=(up^{k}+1)^p=\sum \limits_{l=0}^{p}\binom{p}{l}(up^k)^l=1+up^{k+1}+"..."$, where $"..."$ is divided by $p^{k+1}$. So $a^{p^{k}(p-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod {p^{k+1}} $.

We deduce the same thing for all $l\ge 1$.

Then we have : $K=a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)q^{l-1}(q-1)}= (a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)})^{q^{l-1}(q-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$ and also  $K=a^{q^{l-1}(q-1)p^{k-1}(p-1)}=(a^{q^{l-1}(q-1)})^{p^{k-1}(p-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod{q^l}$

So now, we can say that there exists $\nu$ and $\mu$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that : $K=\nu p^k +1=\mu q^l +1$

Then $\nu p^k=\mu q^l$. With the fact that $\gcd(p^k,q^l)=1$ we have by Gauss lemma $p^l$ which divides $\mu$. So there exists $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mu=\epsilon p^k$ and finally $K=\epsilon p^kq^l+1$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is totally not true.  Take $p=3, q=5, k=2, l=1$ so the modulus is $45$ and the exponent is $16$.  But $2^{16} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{45}$.

Comment: @ErickWong my mistake I was thinking that $\phi(p^k)=k(p-1)$ but it's purely false...

Comment: @user236182 it's the case with Bézout's theorem, you have $au+vp=1$ and $ax+wq=1$. By multiplying the two equations you obtain $1=a^2 xu+vwpq+auwq+axvp=a(xua+uwq+xvp)+vwpq$ with $(xua+uwq+xvp), (vw)\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If $\gcd(a,pq)=1$, then it's simply true by Euler's theorem.

Comment: @user236182 It seems to work I will detail my post, but before I need a fomal proof of if $\gcd(p,q)=1$ then $\gcd(p^k,q^l)=1$

Comment: @Maman If $a,k,l\in\mathbb Z$, $k,l\ge 1$, $p,q$ are different primes, $\gcd\left(a,p^k q^l\right)=1$ (i.e. $\gcd(a,pq)=1$, or i.e. $p\nmid a$ and $q\nmid a$), then by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), since $\phi\left(p^k q^l\right)=p^{k-1}(p-1)q^{l-1}(q-1)$, we get $a^{p^{k-1}(p-1)q^{l-1}(q-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{p^k q^l}$.

Comment: @user236182 You're perfectly right but it's not the method required in the question

Comment: @user236182 No, there were two edits to the title.  You can infer from Maman's first comment that the exponent used to be $k(p-1)l(q-1)$.

Comment: Your proof is good. What is the question?

Comment: @S.Y It was just an edit to change the hypothesis now it's clearer. I answered to my own question because I was just wondering if there were other methods more elementary than these powerful theorems. I found it and re-wrote.